# Book about death for goyim

Tags: product-recommendation, death

Does anyone have a recommendation for a book about losing a loved one which is for Goyim but from a Jewish perspective?

Back story; when my father sat shiva, a family friend gifted him 'The Jewish Way In Death and Mourning'. My father said it helped him a lot during a tough period. A business colleague just lost his Father suddenly and I was hoping to gift him a book which might help him deal with the loss.

Thanks in advance!